# What free raw processing programs can use ColorChecker DCP profiles?

Tags: software, raw

I know that Lightroom can use the ColorChecker Passport profiles. But can other free program (on windows) use the DCP profile directly?

It seems that RawTherapee can use it but after decompiling the matrix inside the profile. But I'm looking for a simpler way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try  dcptool, a free command-line tool for windows and MacOS, downloadable from here:
 http://dcptool.sourceforge.net/Introduction.html

dcpTool can do five things:

1. Decompile binary format DCP files into a text based XML format. This XML file can then be studied and/or edited with a text editor or specialized XML tool.
2. Compile XML format DCP files into binary files that can be used with any DCP aware software.
3. Extract DCP profiles that are embedded into DNG files into a separate DCP file.
4. Make a profile Invariate. An invariate profile won’t cause changes tint when you make adjustments to exposure settings. More on this  on the Hue Twists page.
5. Untwist a profile. An invariate profile won’t change color when you adjust exposure settings, but still has hue twists embedded within it. Untwisting a profile removes all hue twists completely. More on this on the Hue Twists page.

There is a free graphical front-end for dcpTool called dcpEdit. 
dcpEdit is written by Michael Hußmann, writer for German magazine [docma](http://www.docma.info). You must [register with their website](http://www.docma.info/11280.html) to get a free download linkto dcpEdit.

Comment: I have readed about it. I gess I'll take a look. Probably it is easier than it sounds. :o)